# How to read 7 bytes long Desfire uid using rc522 and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, rfid, mifare

I use this library https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python to read UID using rc522 reader and Raspberry Pi. It works great for cards with 4 bytes long uid but I am unable to read 7 bytes long Desfire uid. I read that it is necessary to edit anti collision algorithm when cascade bit is 1. How to modify this library to be able to read 7 bytes long uid ?

Answer (score 1):

I have just come here with the same problem. Although more than 4 years have passed, maybe my solution can help someone.

1) Rename (or delete) the current MFRC522-python library

```
cd ~/.local/lib/python2.7  # or your python version
mv pirc522 pirc522_original
```

2) Create a new directory (if it does not exists) for the installation of a new library

```
mkdir /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages  # or your python version
```

3) Install this other version of the library, which contains a function `anticoll2()` that allows you to read more bytes from the RFID Card

```
git clone https://github.com/ondryaso/pi-rc522.git
cd pi-rc522
python setup.py install
```

And that's all. You can import this new library the same way you imported the previous one.

Now, to read a RFID card, remember that a 7-bytes RFID card starts with `0x88`. So you can use the new function `anticoll2()` in this library  to read more data when `anticoll()` returns `0x88` on the first position. Here's is an example:

```
from pirc522 import RFID

def detect_uid(reader):
    (error, tag_type) = reader.request()
    (error, uid) = reader.anticoll()

    if uid[0] != 0x88:
        rfid_uid = uid[0:4]  # classic 4bytes-rfid card
    else:
        (error, uid2) = reader.anticoll2()
        rfid_uid = uid[1:4] + uid2[:4]  # 7bytes-rfid card

    return rfid_uid


reader = pirc522.RFID()
print("UID: " + str(detect_uid(reader)))
```